# Can't center div aligned to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have got a problem with centering div that is aligned to the bottom, how I may solve it? Tried already some soultion from SO, but didn't help at all.

**HTML**

```
    <div class = "header">
        <div class = "header1"><h1>-</h2></div>
        <div class = "header2"><h1>-</h1></div>
        <div class = "header3"><h1>-</h1></div>
        <div style = "clear:both"/>
        <div class = "header4">-</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header{
    min-height:85vh;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) ), url('bck.jpg');

    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**Div, that I'd like to center**

```
.header4{
background-color:yellow;
height:200px;
width:300px;

font-size:48px;
font-family: 'VT323', monospace;

position:absolute;
bottom:0;
margin-top:auto;

}
```

Comment: You can not close a div with `/>`. It needs a closing tag `</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can center that div using `margin: 0 auto;` with `left: 0;` and `right: 0;`. Try the code below.

```css
.header{
  min-height:85vh;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) ), url('bck.jpg');
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
}

.header4 {
  background-color:yellow;
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
  font-size:48px;
  font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class = "header">
  <div class = "header1"><h1>-</h2></div>
  <div class = "header2"><h1>-</h1></div>
  <div class = "header3"><h1>-</h1></div>
  <div style = "clear:both"/>
  <div class = "header4">-</div>
</div>
```